# Rename the "snow" tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[snow](/questions/tagged/snow) was used in some question instead of [snow-leopard](/questions/tagged/snow-leopard), and one question used it because the question was about snow.

The tag should probably be renamed, as users sometimes use it instead of [snow-leopard](/questions/tagged/snow-leopard) (well, in few questions both the tags were used).
Probably [r-snow](/questions/tagged/r-snow) or [snow-package](/questions/tagged/snow-package) would help to avoid users misuse the tag. It would also help if the tag had a Wiki page that explain exactly what the tag is for.

Comment: Submitted a tag wiki edit, but if it was incomplete, would probably get rejected. You're free to propose it yourself to clear up the snowstorm.

Comment: @random I would, but I cannot propose any tag wikis, for the next seven days.

Comment: Snow isn't burninated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[snow is a package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html) used in the R programming language.

It shouldn't be removed just because people mistagged it when they were referring to [snow-leopard](/questions/tagged/snow-leopard).

A brief clear up in the tag wiki will help things and may not require a rename. The suggested tag wiki (and excerpts) should mention its relation to the R programming language lest we find ourselves here again.

And we probably will since some people tag with spaces before reading and carry over any number of tagging convention/behaviour from other sites.

Comment: I think it should be renamed to something like [r-snow], as otherwise it is too generic of a term.

Comment: I apologize: I misunderstood your previous answer. I am going to edit this question.